# These two tags could get [compressed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have both:

- [compression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compression) × 185 (19 asked this year)

  > the process in which a file or folder's size is reduced by using an algorithm to encode the same information using fewer bits.
- [decompress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/decompress) × 21 (1 asked this year)

  > *no description*

I think we can safely get rid of [decompress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/decompress) by retagging all questions with [compression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compression) instead. Probably we should add a tag synonym like [decompression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/decompression) instead though, to prevent people from recreating that tag.

Opinions? I'd be happy to edit those 21 questions and change the tags if there's positive feedback, but I can't currently suggest synonyms on [compression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compression).

Comment: IMO making synonyms would be better. Can we also consider `mount` and `unmount` as synonyms?

Comment: @Kulfy `mount`/`unmount` should be a separate question. I would not want `decompress` at all though, `compression`/`decompression` makes a much better synonym pair as it's grammatically the same thing.

Comment: Should we consider the [`archive`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/archive) tag with this as well?

Comment: @Dan  No. "An archive file is a collection of files and directories that are stored in one file. The archive file is not compressed — it uses the same amount of disk space as all the individual files and directories combined. A compressed file is a collection of files and directories that are stored in one file and stored in a way that uses less disk space than all the individual files and directories combined."  ([taken from this page](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat7.3/rhl-gsg-en-7.3/s1-managing-compressing-archiving.html))

Comment: @ByteCommander `zip` and `compress` could be good synonyms to `compression` too.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider I don't think `compress` adds any value to `compression` - if you enter one the other will be suggested automatically. And I (personally) absolutely disagree with `zip` because then we would have to merge all other compression format tags like `gzip`, `7zip`, `rar` etc too, which would make us lose information.

Comment: @ByteCommander I support your idea of a synonym pair `compression / decompression` because as you say, it will come up with any of several variants of the word compress then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I now got elected as a moderator since I suggested this, and the community feedback was overall positive, I just carried the proposed changes out myself.

1. [decompress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/decompress) no longer exists, I renamed it to [decompression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/decompression).
2. [decompression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/decompression) is now a synonym for [compression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/compression). All searches for this tag will now redirect to the master tag, and you will also see the master tag as suggestion when you want to tag a question.